# About Airbnb homepage video background, how does it detect users' devices?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, user-agent

If you use Chrome on a PC/MAC to visit [Airbnb](https://www.airbnb.com.au), and resize your window to 1024px*768px, you will get video jumbotron; and if you use an iPad to visit Airbnb, which window size is also 1024px*768px, this time you will see an image carousel jumbotron instead of the video one.

The question is, how to make this happen? Could anyone point out the exact code piece regarding to device detection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have code checking for iPad in User Agent field in their Javascript (You can check it from Chrome development console).

You have plenty of JavaScript Device detection libraries in the Internet. Most of them perform User-Agent string parsing and matching.

You can check [this](http://hgoebl.github.io/mobile-detect.js/) library.